# Can I do a conditional in the rails form builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so i have this test_field

```
   = f.text_field :profile_count, :readonly => true
```

I only need the readonly to be there is the user is not an admin?

so I can do this

```
if current_user.admin?
   = f.text_field :profile_count
else
   = f.text_field :profile_count, :readonly => true
```

but is there a way to make it more compact or more rails like also readonly is not 100% ideal either because users can manipulate the dom via firebug or something..any suggestions

Comment: Don't show it as a form value if they can't submit it. You'd still need to handle that on the server side though, if you're using mass assignment.

Comment: any suggestions on how to display it to the user then

Comment: I still need to have it there so the user can view it but only admins can change it

Answer (score 1):

To make it more compact, just do `= f.text_field :profile_count, :readonly => !current_user.admin?`

Regarding your concern about a user editing the text box in spite of the readonly setting, you can check `admin?` in your controller before saving profile_count changes.